# hibernate-validator - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hibernate-validator

I am switching to JakartaEE 10 and therefore im trying to update my `hibernate-validator` from `5.4.0.Final` to `8.0.0.Final`, but I just can't get rid of the following error thats thrown in a lot of my tests:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl`

I've read that you have to include

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>
    <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

now, which I did, but I'm still receiving this error. Answers to related questions referencing older versions of `hibernate-validator` assume a dependency mismatch, but I cannot spot it from the dependency tree of the module thats failing to build:

```xml
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ evb-ext-services ---
[INFO] de.mygroupid.evb:evb-ext-services:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-business:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-domain:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-ips-jpa:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.expressly:expressly:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-gdv-modell:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-hooks:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-auth:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mygroupid:mygroupid-runtime:jar:23.6.0.a20230310-01:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mygroupid:mygroupid-valuetypes:jar:23.6.0.a20230310-01:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-business-api:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-base:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-cdi:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.lang-model:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.interceptor:jakarta.interceptor-api:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:6.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.138:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.25.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models-jakarta:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations-jakarta:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration-jakarta:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core-jakarta:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:jakarta:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-business:test-jar:tests:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.evb:evb-test-nachrichten:jar:23.6.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.7:test
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.7:test
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-jax-rs:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-auth-test:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:test
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-cdi-test:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:test
[INFO] |  +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-test:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.weld:weld-junit5:jar:4.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:jar:5.0.0.SP1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.weld.environment:weld-environment-common:jar:5.0.0.SP1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.weld:weld-lite-extension-translator:jar:5.0.0.SP1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-processor:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.jboss.jdeparser:jdeparser:jar:2.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.weld.probe:weld-probe-core:jar:5.0.0.SP1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.weld:weld-junit-common:jar:4.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |     \- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.weld:weld-core-impl:jar:5.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.weld:weld-api:jar:5.0.SP3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.weld:weld-spi:jar:5.0.SP3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.classfilewriter:jboss-classfilewriter:jar:1.2.5.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.weld.module:weld-jta:jar:5.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta-jakarta:jar:5.13.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jboss-transaction-spi-jakarta:jar:7.6.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.resource:jakarta.resource-api:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.naming:jnpserver:jar:5.0.5.Final:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:2.2.10.GA:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA:test
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-ips-test:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mygroupid:mygroupid-testsupport:jar:23.6.0.a20230310-01:test
[INFO] +- de.mygroupid.commons:commons-ips:jar:23.6.0-a20230503-02:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.1.4.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:jar:1.0.1.Beta1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs-services:jar:3.1.4.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.23:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.23:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:2.0.7:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:test
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:4.0.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:jar:4.5.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you any idea how to get rid of this error then any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run your tests? Is there any app server involved that might contain a different jar version? Also, while it might not be related, I've noticed that you only have a dependency on the validator in evb-domain. If you are making explicit validator calls in evb-ext-services it's better to list the dependency there as well.

Comment: I was able to figure out which dependency caused the error. but now my JPA tests take ages to finish for some reason.. Whereever i call `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()` it takes 20 seconds or so... I suspect the update`hibernate-validator` to be the cause, but cannot explain why.

Comment: Glad you've figured out what was the original problem. If you are upgrading to Jakarta 10 I suspect you are also upgrading the ORM alongside the Validator. Try to get an isolated test and enable query logging - see if the amount of queries is +/- the same as before. If so, try to set the property `javax.persistence.validation.mode` to `none` and see how it performs with validation disabled.

Comment: I have enabled eclipselink logging and started a single test where i call `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()` and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()`. There is just 2 queries in between, so apparently the amount of queries is not the problem. No idea whats the problem here...

Comment: Yeah, I have rolled back the update of `hibernate-validator` and now my tests are running at a reasonable speed again.. I can't tell why hibernate-validator slows down the `EntityManager` commit so much, but for the time being I will try to stick with `5.4.0.Final`.

Comment: It might be related to something like - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1928. If you are seeing the degraded performance and can create a reproducer and report it here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV that would be nice. Reproducer templates can be found here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, in my scenario, the dependency causing this error is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After commenting it out the error vanished.